# dispatcher.d script not executing

Tags: 13.10, network-manager

I'm currently working on script , which will change proxy and apt settings depending on network in which the Laptop will be plugged in.

Problem is that, if i run the script from terminal, everything works fine. But as soon as

I place it in the `/etc/Networkmanager/dispatcher.d/` , according to syslog, nothing happens.

Permissions :

> -rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 1163 máj 30 12:23 02ifupproxy*

This is the script:

```sh
#!/bin/bash

#Script for proxy auto detection.
aptconf="/etc/apt/apt.conf"
aptconfd="/etc/apt/apt.conf.d/01proxy"
adapter=`ps -ef | grep eth| grep root | awk '{ print $18}'`
ipaddres=`ifconfig $adapter | grep inet\ addr | awk -F ":" '{print $2}' | awk '{print $1}'`
ipaddrA=`echo $ipaddres | awk -F "." '{print $1}'`
ipaddrB=`echo $ipaddres | awk -F "." '{print $2}'`
ipaddrC=`echo $ipaddres | awk -F "." '{print $3}'`

if [ $ipaddrA -eq 192 ] && [ $ipaddrB -eq 168 ] && [ $ipaddrC -ge 129 ] && [ $ipaddrC -le 140 ] ; then
 ping -c 3 192.168.143.57

 if [ $? -eq 0 ] ; then

  if [ -f $aptconfd  ] ;then
     echo "Acquire::http::Proxy \"http://192.168.143.57:3142\";" > $aptconfd

     notify-send -i /usr/share/icons/gnome/32x32/status/network-receive.png Settings\ changed\ for\ Gratex\ Proxy

     gsettings set org.gnome.system.proxy mode 'manual'



  fi


fi



else 

notify-send -i /usr/share/icons/gnome/48x48/status/network-error.png Settings\ changed\ for\ Outside
gsettings set org.gnome.system.proxy mode 'none'
echo "" > $aptconfd

fi
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to put script in `/etc/network/if-up.d/`

Example script witch add route if interface up

```
# Check for specific interface if desired
[ "$IFACE" != "usb0" ] || exit 0
# Adding additional routes on connection
route add default dev usb0 via 192.168.42.129
route add ...
route add ...
```

Comment: I've tried doing so, but it didn't help.

Comment: OK, I found a problem.
I'm getting 
>dconf-WARNING **: failed to commit changes to dconf: Error spawning command line 'dbus-launch --autolaunch=2191703b14511e102d03725952a1800e --binary-syntax --close-stderr': Child process exited with code 1